# T-SQL update with restrictions in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

**SOLVED IT**

This will do it:

```
UPDATE myTable
  SET
    URL = 
       ( CASE 
            WHEN (URL <> 'new domain' THEN 'new domain'
            ELSE URL
         END
       )
  WHERE
    NAME = 'any name'
```

---

Good Morning,

I have an UPDATE query with a little problem.
The query shall update the existing URL column.
BUT ... the WHERE clause has two restrictions build up on each other.

First and main restriction is the NAME column. This column is unique.
Now I want to check if that URL in the database is equal to the new one.
And only if there is a difference I want to replace it.

```
UPDATE myTable
  SET
    URL = 'new domain'
  WHERE
    NAME = 'any name' AND
    URL <> 'new domain'
```

This UPDATE query will look for the name but also for every domain that doesn't match this pattern.
Not what I want.

Comment: Did your first attempt that you modified according to my answer not what you wanted? Actually it should, and it is more efficient than your new solution because it performs only updates that are really needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update only if there is really a change, the value for URL in the SET-clause should be the same as in the WHERE-clause. In your example they are different.

Comment: Ok, my fault. I changed it.

Comment: I found this here in the MSDN and will try it:

`USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
UPDATE HumanResources.Employee  
SET VacationHours =   
    ( CASE  
         WHEN ((VacationHours - 10.00) < 0) THEN VacationHours + 40    
         ELSE (VacationHours + 20.00)  
       END  
    )  
OUTPUT Deleted.BusinessEntityID, Deleted.VacationHours AS   BeforeValue,   
       Inserted.VacationHours AS AfterValue  
WHERE SalariedFlag = 0;   
`

Comment: Hi Drunix, sorry for the late answer. Unfortunately it didn't work. I've used that first original statement at the top with WHERE Name ... AND URL. And that results that every of my 200 records got an update. In real there should be only 7-8 updates that have a different URL.

Comment: STOP, everything is ok. I tested with odbc_num_rows($result) and there I could see that only the 7-8 wrong rows were updated.

Comment: Then you should remove your solution because it does unecessary updates.